# Different callback orders when using fs.readFile with and without error

Tags: node.js, event-loop

When I run the following code

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function sleep(ms) {
  let stop = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < stop + ms) {}
}

function onRead(error, data) {
  console.log("in onRead");
}

function hello() {
  console.log("hello");
}

fs.readFile(__filename, onRead);

// Block 500ms to make sure the file is read
sleep(500);

console.log("hi");
setImmediate(hello);
```

It prints

```
hi
hello
in onRead
```

to the terminal.

If I change it to

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function sleep(ms) {
  let stop = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < stop + ms) {}
}

function onRead(error, data) {
  console.log("in onRead");
}

function hello() {
  console.log("hello");
}

// Now we are trying to read a non-existent file
fs.readFile("non-exist", onRead);

sleep(500);

console.log("hi");
setImmediate(hello);
```

It prints

```
hi
in onRead
hello
```

What makes the difference between the order of execution of `onRead` and `hello`?

Comment: It may be platform dependent. I have the same output in Windows 10 x64 with Node.js 14.2.0 and 15.0.0 (nightly or canary).

Comment: I have tested this on macOS 10.14 with node v8.16.1, v10.16.3, v12.10.0, v14.2.0.

Comment: To be clear: I have identical output in both cases: `hi - hello - in onRead`.

Answer (score 0):

fs.readFile is async, `onRead` is called when nodejs has completed reading file and found data or returning an error. So it is obvious for `console.log("hi")` to be called before result from `fs.readFile` is available.  Second output depends how fast fs.readFile returns results. fs.readFile is slower in first scenarion than in second scenarion hence the difference in order second outputs between the two scenarios.

This also has much to do with how NodeJs event loop executes its phases.

These articles on NodeJs event loop execution ordering contain much information [The Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) and [Understanding the Node.js event loop phases](https://dev.to/lunaticmonk/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop-phases-and-how-it-executes-the-javascript-code-1j9)

Comment: This does not seem to be the case. If I add a delay of 500 milliseconds to make sure the file is read (I have updated the snippets), the results remain the same.

Comment: Check out articles links I have attached to my aswer. They explain in deep how Node JS event loop executes.

Comment: I have already read them. But they did not make it clear to me why we have such a difference when using fs.readFile with and without error. Also, from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986260/different-callback-orders-when-using-fs-readfile-with-and-without-error#comment109632991_61986260), it seems to be platform-dependent.